# Find k closest points in large number of points

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, computer-science

Assume that we have 1 billion points in 3 dimensional space (or 2d, it doesn't matter at the moment), we want to find `k closest points` (a subset of points with size k that are closer to each other than any other such subset), how can we do that ?

I know that there's a data structure called [cover tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_tree) but I guess it might not be useful here as it tries to find nodes which are closest to one point.

Comment: [Spatial indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database#Spatial_index) may come in handy.

Comment: Actually there is a long list of them, I know R-tree and specially Kd-tree , but I guess these work same as cover tree here, we can use these structures to find the the closest nodes to a single node.

Comment: Actually I think we can use for example the `kd-tree` data structure to store the nodes and then by doing a kind of in-order traversal of the nodes and keeping a `queue` of fixed length (k) we can find the points which are closest together , this will take `O(nlogn)` for creating the kd-tree and `O(n)` to traverse all of the nodes, so the total time would be `O(nlogn)` , any idea ?

Comment: There are `k(k-1)/2` distances in a set of `k` points. What should be minimized? Sum? Maximum? Something else?

Comment: @n.m. Sum of the distances between each two node has to be minimized
And you are right there are `k(k-1)/2` distances , but we can do that in `O(n)`, because we add a new point to the `queue` we have distances between other nodes , so this can be done in `O(k)`

Comment: You figure it out. kd-tree is the most widely used technique to query knn with an average O(log N). You may also consider an approximation: check the approximate bbd-tree by Arya et al. 
Mount and Arya have a fast library for knn (http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/)

Comment: Have you found a solution to this "find `k` closest vectors among `n`" problem?

Answer (score 0):

That seems like an ideal problem for the [K-Means Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering), your results should look like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/10/Iris_Flowers_Clustering_kMeans.svg)